# Issue adding key value pair to javascript object from an array

Tags: javascript

I have an object like this

```
let obj = {
    "apple": {
    "color": "red",
  },
  "banana": {
    "color": "yellow"
  }
}
```

I am getting an array of objects of this form

```
let arr = [
  {
    "count": "9904",
    "fruit": "apple",
    "type": "typea"
  },
    {
    "count": "7142",
    "fruit": "banana",
    "type": "typeb"
  },
  {
    "count": "4121",
    "fruit": "apple",
    "type": "typec"
  }
]
```

I want to combine these two so that each item in `obj`can have variable no of properties so that final output look something like this

```
{
    "apple": {
    "color": "red",
    "typea": "9904",
    "typec": "4121"
  },
  "banana": {
    "color": "yellow",
    "typeb": "7142"
  }
}
```

I tried running the array through a for loop but when I try to use the dynamic values in keys it shows error

```
for (let item of arr){
    obj[item.fruit] = {...obj[item.fruit], item.type: item.count}
}
```

If instead of `item.type` I put some static value like `"count"` it works but I can't figure out how to use dynamic value

Can anyone suggest me what is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Show us what you've tried first.

Comment: @djcaesar9114 Edited the question to include method I used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use computed property names with square brackets.

```js
let obj = {
    "apple": {
    "color": "red",
  },
  "banana": {
    "color": "yellow"
  }
}
let arr = [
  {
    "count": "9904",
    "fruit": "apple",
    "type": "typea"
  },
    {
    "count": "7142",
    "fruit": "banana",
    "type": "typeb"
  },
  {
    "count": "4121",
    "fruit": "apple",
    "type": "typec"
  }
]
for (let item of arr){
    obj[item.fruit] = {...obj[item.fruit], [item.type]: item.count}
}
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a verbose and explicit example of how you can do this using [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).
(Note that MDN will be down for maintenance for up to an hour at some point today.)

```js
const
  obj = { apple:{color:"red"}, banana:{color:"yellow"} },
  arr = [
    { fruit: "apple",  type: "typeA", count: 9 },
    { fruit: "banana", type: "typeB", count: 7 },
    { fruit: "apple",  type: "typeC", count: 4 }
  ];
arr.reduce( (theObj, current) => {
  // Reduce loops through the array, updating theObj for each item
  const
    fruitName = current.fruit, // Gets fruit name
    fruitObjInObj = theObj[fruitName], // Gets fruit obj
    type = current.type, // Gets type from current item
    count = current.count; // Gets count from current item
  fruitObjInObj[type] = count; // Adds property to fruit obj
  return theObj; // Gives theObj back to `reduce` for next loop
}, obj); // Tells `reduce` to use obj as theObj on first loop

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Thanks. Very elegant. Didn't know reduce can used in this way also